# How to descibe endpoints in the redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml

I got error

"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeClusters operation: User: arn:aws:sts::XX:assumed-role/xx/axx is not authorized to perform: redshift:DescribeClusters on resource: arn:aws:xx:*",

For RDS below is the code

```
client = boto3.client('rds')
cluster_list = client.describe_db_cluster_endpoints()
print(cluster_list)
```

For redshift below is the code

```
client = boto3.client('redshift', 'us-east-2')
cluster_list = client.describe_clusters()
print(cluster_list)
```

My I am role have below service is below

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters: 

  testlambdarole:
    Type: String
    Default: role-name
      
Resources: 

  Role:  
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref testlambdarole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'               
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
                - redshift.amazonaws.com
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']      
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: RdsAccess
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action: 
                  - rds-db:connect
                Resource: "*"
```

Comment: Your IAM Role doesn't have permission to perform that action, like the error says.

Comment: You can see - redshift.amazonaws.com is present

Comment: Redshift is mentioned as a Service Principal, please read the IAM documentation.

Comment: you mean to say i need to add the policy also?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: i have added 
                                - rds-db:connect
                                - rds-db:DescribeDBClusterEndpoints   its not working

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: for RDS access denied , I have tried with -rds:DescribeDBClusterEndpoints also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a policy in your IAM Role that allows the action you want to perform on Redshift, something like this:

```yaml
- PolicyName: RSDescribeClusters
  PolicyDocument: 
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement: 
      - Effect: "Allow"
      Action: 
        - redshift:DescribeClusters
      Resource: "*"
```

From the way you have set it, you're simply allowing the Redshift service to assume that IAM Role.

The `redshift:DescribeClusters` action was specified in the error message you posted; additionally you can find all the actions supported by Redshift on the [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonredshift.html) page of the Developer Documentation.

If for instance you want to add one for RDS, to do the same you can use this (tested and it works):

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds:DescribeDBClusterEndpoints",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster-endpoint:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You need to replace your Account ID and/or convert it to CloudFormation yourself.

Comment: How you got this redshift:DescribeClusters

Comment: also please add for RDS describe_db_cluster_endpoints

Comment: Added clarification, you can find all the actions for each service on the AWS documentation, you can generally google something like "iam service actions" (i.e. "iam redshift actions" or "iam rds actions")

Comment: i have added 
                                - rds-db:connect
                                - rds-db:DescribeDBClusterEndpoints   its not working

Comment: Added an example I have tested and that works. This is my last edit, good luck.

Comment: can you answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245051/what-are-the-action-and-resource-to-connect-the-rds