# What are the action and resource to connect the RDS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Lambda role have below permissions

```
"Action" : "rds-db:connect"

"Resource":  "arn:aws:rds:*:6548938434:cluster:*"
```

Code is below

```
import pg8000
#region is us-east-2b
client = boto3.client(service_name='rds',
                      region_name='us-east-2')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
   conn = pg8000.connect(database='postgres', user='test_user',\
                          password='1234567', \
                          host='abc-dev-chhd674.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com', \
                          port=5432, ssl_context=True)
```

I have connection timed out issue

Comment: `rds-db:connect` is only for IAM auth for RDS. You seem to be using traditional connection. So the IAM permissions do not apply to your case.

Comment: Also what are RDS security groups if you have timeout? Is your lambda in VPC?

Comment: @Marcin Yes , Thank you. Its working now, VPC. My lambda is in VPC

Comment: @Marcin if i want to connect all the RDS below resource will work right - Resource `arn:aws:rds:*:6548938434:*
 - arn:aws:rds:*`